Согласование прилагательного во множественном числе с однородным членом в единственном
Является ли корректным такое согласование: «Совместные обеды, просмотр телевизора и т.д.»? Или же нужно повторять слово «...совместный просмотр...»?

Пример предложения:
Совместные обеды, просмотр телевизора и т.д. объединяют людей.
Пояснение

Повтор определения не нужен, так как по смыслу ясно, что оно относится ко всем членам однородного ряда.

Выбор формы числа определения зависит от различных факторов и регулируется правилом: Розенталь §195. Определение при существительных – однородных членах.

В этой теме надо учитывать влияние различных факторов, поэтому решение всегда конкретно.


Определение стоит в форме мн. числа для первого однородного члена, и в этой форме оно относится ко всем членам ряда (выбор ед. числа невозможен). Учитывается препозиция определения, сказуемое также ставится в форме мн. числа.

Сравнить: Совместный отдых, просмотр телевизора (= совместное действие) объединяет людей. Здесь переход к форме ед. числа выглядит закономерно.


Благодарю за ответ и за источник. Очень помогли.
